# Simple PHP not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a ajax notification and this is part of my system allowing a user to favorite, or archive, that notification. The problem is that this php code below won't work and there is no error in the queries because the `or die` returns nothing. What is returned is just `error`. That is all it is echoing. I know the javascript is correct and sending the correct information because I have checked the network tab to see. Are there any major errors that I am missing?

```
<?php
require_once('.conf.php');
$notid = mysql_real_escape_string($get['notification_id']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['uname']);
$action = mysql_real_escape_string($get['action']);

if ($action == 'add') {
    $insert = mysql_query("UPDATE updates SET object_fav = 1 WHERE username = '$username' AND id = '$notid'") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    echo 'success';
} elseif($action == 'sub') {
    $remove = mysql_query("UPDATE updates SET object_fav = 0 WHERE username = '$username' AND id = '$notid'") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    echo 'remove';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has no default array called `$get`. Perhaps you intend to use [the `$_GET` superglobal.](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['action']);
$notid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['notification_id']);
```

It prints `error` when `$action` is not matched in your `if/else` chain, because the variable isn't correctly set.

Be sure that you are developing with `display_errors` turned on, and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. The undefined variable `$get` would display warnings on screen.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```